# Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing

Tags: javascript, jshint

### This is a jshint warning question.How can I solve this problem?

```
var comment_btn=document.querySelector('.comment_button');
var comment_ul=document.querySelector('.comment_ul');
var comment_text=document.querySelector('#comment');

comment_btn.onclick = function(){
    var comment_li = document.createElement('li');
    comment_li.className = 'comment_li';
    if(comment_text.value != '') {
        comment_li.innerHTML = comment_text.value + "<a class='comment_a' href='javascript:;'>Delete</a>";
        comment_ul.insertBefore(comment_li,comment_ul.children[0]);
        var del = document.querySelectorAll('.comment_a');
        for (var i = 0; i < del.length; i++) {
            del[i].onclick = function() {
                comment_ul.removeChild(this.parentNode);
            };
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Please input!');
    }
};
```

*Warning:*
*Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (comment_ul) (W083)jshint(W083)*

I really can't think of a solution,please help me.

Comment: See if the following explanation helps, JS documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: `var del = document.querySelectorAll('.comment_a');` is going to select every element on the page. So if you click `comment_btn` more than once you will be adding a lot of events. You should only be selecting the `a` in the li you create. You should not have to loop at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you add a new li, you are selecting EVERY delete anchor and adding another click event to it.

You should not be looping at all. You should just be selecting the anchor in the li you create and attach the event to that.

```js
const comment_ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const comment_text = document.querySelector("#comment_text");


comment_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!comment_text.value.length) {
    alert('Please input!');
    return;
  }

  var comment_li = document.createElement('li');

  comment_li.className = 'comment_li';

  comment_li.innerHTML = comment_text.value + "<a class='comment_a' href='javascript:;'>Delete</a>";

  comment_ul.insertBefore(comment_li, comment_ul.children[0]);

  var del = comment_li.querySelector('.comment_a');
  del.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    comment_ul.removeChild(this.parentNode);
  });

});
```

```html
<ul></ul>

<input type="text" id="comment_text" />
<button id="comment_btn">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you assign to `onclick` inside the loop doesn't care about any value that changes during the course of the loop. It only uses `comment_url` (defined before the loop) and `this`.

Create the function before the loop and assign it to a variable.

Copy it to `onclick` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning which will appear if you have a loop and you have a variable declared with `var`, which [can sometimes cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Assuming you aren't reassigning `comment_ul` anywhere, the problems aren't relevant to your situation, so all you need to do is make the linter happy.

One approach would be to declare the variable with `const` instead (best to declare variables with `const` when possible, and `let` when not).

```
const comment_ul = document.querySelector('.comment_ul');
```

Another would be to use `forEach` instead of `for(...`.

That said, your code looks buggy at the moment - you're adding an event listener to every button every time `comment_btn` is clicked. Instead of doing that, consider adding only a single listener, ever - use event delegation. If the clicked element or one of its ancestors is a `.comment_a`, remove its parent.

```
commentContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const a = event.target.closest('.comment_a');
  if (a) {
    a.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: "*use forEach instead of for(....*" - I don't think that would help. It may shut up the linter, but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty confident `comment_ul` isn't being reassigned, in which case there's no problem to solve, other than shutting up the linter.